# graphql how to open query variables panel

Tags: graphql

I am new to GraphQl and wondering how do I add the query variables panel in the Graphql interface? I read many docs and looks like they all have the query variables panel by default, but not my case, any ideas? tks.

My graphql view
[image]

Expected graphql view
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution is simply append the `&variables=YOUR_VARIABLES` querystring parameter to the graphql url to make it appear